# entity framework change database physical location by class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I am new to entity framework. I wrote a simple code first database.
how to change the physical location of database.mdf by class. let's say i what to save my database in |DataDirectory|\App_Data\database.mdf. I am using windows forms.
here is the DbContext

```
 class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext()
        : base("database")
    { }
    public DbSet<Login> Logins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<master> masters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<People> People { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the configuration file app.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>`
```

thanks for you time and please help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just declare another constructor on your database context where you send in the location of the database.

```
public DatabaseContext(string connection) : base(connection)  { }
```

Notice the call to the `base()`, the base class constructor. 
According to [EF Spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx), you can pass in

- An existing connection to a database
- The name of a connection string contained in the .config
- A connection string

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you write example please of the string

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\yourdbfilenamehere.mdf;Initial Catalog=yourdatabasenamehere;Integrated Security=True"